# C# WPF Combobox with textbox as element set width of textbox as width of combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a combobox with Textboxes as Items i like to set the width of Textboxes to the width of Combobox. So at moment the Textbox expand with the size of text but it should wrap when width is the same as the combobox...
this is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox  
            Margin="51,146,238,146"
            BorderThickness="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"                                                   
            Padding="3" Height="20" IsEditable="True"
            x:Name="testCombobox" SelectionChanged="testCombobox_SelectionChanged">


            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox 
                                                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                    AcceptsReturn="True"

                                                    Padding="1,1,1,1"
                                                    Background="Yellow">
                    </TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the following to stretch the TextBoxes inside the ComboBoxItems:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter
            Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```